# Mixing update/insert records in a single invocation of "Instead of insert, update" - Is that possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to know whether an "instead of insert, update" trigger can be called to both "UPDATE" A records in the table while "INSERTING" B records in a **single invocation**?

Actually, I'm just curious to know whether SQL Server could call the mentioned trigger for updating and inserting records, at once? or it just calls the trigger once for updating some records, and once for inserting some others?

Consider this, for example:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MyTable_DoWhatever] 
   ON  [dbo].[MyTable] 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Updating BIT = 0;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED i INNER JOIN DELETED d ON i.Id = d.Id) SET @Updating = 1

END
```

Does the above @Updating flag valid to determine whether the trigger is called for "INSTEAD OF INSERTED" or "INSTEAD OF UPDATE"?

Thanks.

Comment: I updated the original question...

Comment: Yes, your flag does what you expect, assuming `id` is a unique identifier.  *(If a record is in both `inserted` and `deleted`, it was actually updated.)*

Comment: is it possible that "inserted" table contains some rows that are not in "deleted" table, while at the same time, the "inserted" table contains some rows that are in "deleted" table? (If yes, so the above method isn't correct, since some records are updating while others are inserting at the same time).

Comment: This *can* be caused by using the `MERGE` command, as MERGE can cause all three of INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE - See Books Online.